# psycopg2 rounds my float in SELECT statement

Tags: postgresql, rounding, psycopg2, truncated

I'm writing a quick script to retrieve values from my database using psycopg2. Everything seemed to work fine until I verified the values in my output. I was astonished to realise they were rounded up. I double-checked the values stored and they are correct. So why it this query

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT val, val+0 FROM mytable;')
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows[0])
```

returning

```
(1860500.0, 1860496.0)
 ^ rounded? ^ correct
```

What am I doing wrong? Note: column val is defined as

```
ALTER TABLE public.mytable ADD COLUMN val real;
```

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic.](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `SET extra_float_digits=3` and see if that changes things.

The second value is converted to `numeric` internally because that is the “least common denominator” for `real` and `integer`, and `numeric` is not rounded.

You should use `double precision` rather than `real`.